# "Approve Edit" info page broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

I edited an answer and got a message saying that the edit needed to be peer reviewed before being posted. This was something new to me, so I went to the priviledges page to see what was up. However, the link for `approve edits` is broken.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-edit-suggestion

Since this seems to be a new feature unique to this site, could someone also explain how it works?

Comment: yes, we will be working on that this coming week.

Comment: It's not unique to this site, it's just very new; it was rolled out network-wide about a day ago, and they're still fiddling with it

Answer (score 1):

This should all be working now.